Can an open set of $\Bbb R^n$ be star-shaped with respect to a unique point?
Suppose that $X \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is an open set that is star-shaped with respect to some point $x_0 \in X$.
Can it occur that $x_0$ is the only point with respect to which $X$ is star-shaped?
I can imagine that some open sets with very irregular boundary may have that property.

An unbounded example in $\Bbb R^2$ is $X= { (x;y) : |xy|<1}$. I cannot imagine a bounded example.

@Crostul : see the example of a disk with 2 slits given in the answer to the "duplicate" reference above.
